# Как отнять проценты от числа и добавить в новый столбец DataFrame? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Я создаю новый столбец с названием "Final_Price" в котором добавляю числа из столбца Price отняв 18%. Но отняв проценты я получаю числа с лишними двумя цифрами на конце (10 - 18% = 8.2000).
И я хочу узнать правильно ли я делаю? Может быть есть способ сделать это лучше в Pandas? Или при помощи Numpy?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('Table.html')
df = df[0]

df['Final_Price'] = df['Price'] - (df['Price'] / 100 * 18 )
```

Результат:

| Product | Price | Final_Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Phone 1 | 10 | 8.2000 |
| Phone 2 | 34.99 | 28.6918 |
| Phone 3 | 10 | 8.2000 |
| Phone 4 | 17.50 | 14.3500 |
| Phone 5 | 10 | 8.2000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так работает арифметика чисел с плавающей точкой и в общем случае цифр после десятичной точки/запятой может быть больше чем 4. Pandas по умолчанию показывает четыре знака после точки. Если вам нужно округлить до двух знаков - можно воспользоваться методом `.round(2)`:

```
df['Final_Price'] = (df['Price'] * 0.82).round(2)
```

или:

```
df['Final_Price'] = df['Price'].mul(0.82).round(2)
```

результат:

```
In [220]: df
Out[220]:
   Product  Price  Final_Price
0  Phone 1  10.00         8.20
1  Phone 2  34.99        28.69
2  Phone 3  10.00         8.20
3  Phone 4  17.50        14.35
4  Phone 5  10.00         8.20
```